# How to make ghci support ^p to go up?

Tags: haskell, readline, ghci, haskeline

I use Ctrl p a lot instead of up arrow to go up on Terminal. How to make ghci support Ctrl p to go up?

I use ghci from ghc98 from port. Mac OS X 10.5.8.

Answer (score 8):

[Customize](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/CustomKeyBindings) haskeline, *e.g.*,

```
$ cat ~/.haskeline 
bind: ctrl-p up
```

To enable all the emacs bindings, you can specify that as a [user preference](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/UserPrefs):

```
$ cat ~/.haskeline
editMode: Emacs
```